# Массив переменной длины

Tags: pascal, javascript

Всем здравствуйте. Скажите пожалуйста, как в Паскале (самом обычном) сделать массив переменной длины? Т.е. чтобы юзер сам вводил с клавы его длину. В интернете ничего найти не смог, поэтому задаю вопрос тут. И ещё один вопрос: как, используя ТОЛЬКО html и javascript, напечатать длину массива из тела скрипта. Массив называется 'a'. Если не сложно, приведите весь участок кода.

Comment: странно, что вы НИЧЕГО не нашли в Интернете.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как, используя ТОЛЬКО html и
> javascript, напечатать длину массива
> из тела скрипта. Массив называется
> 'a'. Если не сложно, приведите весь
> участок кода.

Пишете на странице:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; //создали массив из цифр от 1 до 5
    document.write('Длина массива = ');
    document.write(a.length);
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает. А можно сделать так, чтобы при выводе длины не открывалась новая страница, а просто выводилась строчка "Длина массива .. элементов" в том же блоке (сайт на юкозе)?

Comment: Тот код, который я написал не вызывает открытие новой страницы (наверное это происходит по другой причине).
Приведите код, всего вскрипта, попробуем разобраться...

Comment: Отведите отдельный элемент для вывода результата: <div id="rezult"></div>, а потом сделайте так: document.getElementById('rezult').innerHTML = 'blablabla: ' + a.length + ' symbols';

Comment: Вероятно то, что вы называете новой страницей, — это ваша же страница и есть. Просто document.write затирает её целиком, если вызывать его после наступления события onload.

Comment: О! Работает ваш вариант, ling. Спасибо всем, вопрос закрыт (и про массивы тоже).

Answer (score 2):

> Скажите пожалуйста, как в Паскале (самом обычном) сделать массив переменной длины? Т.е. чтобы юзер сам вводил с клавы его длину. В интернете ничего найти не смог, поэтому задаю вопрос тут

1. В паскале как и в любом нормальном :-) языке можно использовать указатели. Минусы - в паскале работа с указателями сделана неудобно.
2. Можно сделать тип массива, размером заведомо больше, чем нужно на практике. И тогда просто используете кусочек от массива. Минусы - серьезный расход лишней памяти. Зато удобно.
3. Можно использовать ["открытые массивы"](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu59.html). Но это не классический паскаль уже. Минусы - завязываетесь на тип компилятора и опции компиляции.

Comment: М-да. Вы ответили как настоящий программист. Просто, понятно и к сожалению, почти бесполезно=) Всё равно почти ничего не понял.

Comment: Единственное, что я могу сделать - использовать второй вариант.

Comment: Второй вариант подошёл лучше всего. Ваш ответ принимаю.

Comment: Тогда отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый :-)

Comment: Вроде нажал на галочку. Но там какой-то обрезанный алерт выскакивает. Сейчас в исходнике погляжу. Но там содержания этого алерта не видно. Теперь узнал, что там написано: "Данный вопрос уже достиг предела принимаемых ответов".

Answer (score 2):

> Скажите пожалуйста, как в Паскале
> (самом обычном) сделать массив
> переменной длины? Т.е. чтобы юзер сам
> вводил с клавы его длину. В интернете
> ничего найти не смог, поэтому задаю
> вопрос тут

**a** - массив переменной длины

объявление:

```
var
   a : array of longint;
```

установка размера n элементов:

```
SetLength(a, n);
```

ну и, чтобы вообще весь код был с динамическим захватом памяти:

объявление:

```
var
   a : array of ^longint;
```

установка размера **n** элементов:

```
SetLength(a, n);
```

установка значения 10 элемента с номером **i**:

```
New(a[i]);
a[i]^ := 10;
```

не забываем про высвобожение памяти :

```
Dispose(a[i]);
```

Comment: Как уже выше отмечали, это не "самый обычный паскаль", т.е. не паскаль Вирта и даже не ANSI-паскаль прошлого тысячилетия.